# Left Outer Join doesn't give expected result. What am I missing?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

My objective is to find records that exist in Table 1 but do not exist in Table2. No record has a NULL value. 
I am using the following code, but it is not giving me the expected results.

```
Select  
    distinct a.fld  
from  
    tbl1 a  
left outer join 
    tbl2 b 
on  
    a.fld= b.fld
where  
    a.fld<> b.fld
```

Most likely the issue is with my where clause, but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Pls Help.

Comment: When you run the query without the where clause and add b.fld to your `SELECT` statement, Do you get `NULL` values? If so, then you can change your `WHERE` statement to `b.fld IS NULL`.

Comment: I suggest you find a good tutorial on SQL. Your comments suggest you don't really understand how outer joins work. To have a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630887/using-is-null-or-is-not-null-on-join-conditions-theory-question/6631535#6631535

Comment: @ypercube - You are right. I have started a job that needed a "little" sql on a case to case basis. Unfortunately, little is subjective. Thanks for the tutorial link. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `JOIN` on your table how about using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.fld
FROM tbl1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl2 b
                  WHERE a.fld = b.fld);
```

This will return all rows in `tbl1` where the `fld` value doesn't exist in `tbl2`

Comment: This also works. Interesting approach. I also noticed that the query is much faster than using joins. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "Table 1" is tbl1a, this should give you what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.fld
FROM tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON a.fld = b.fld
WHERE b.fld IS NULL
```

Comment: This works, what i don't understand, is why {b.fld IS NULL} is needed because really there is a not a single record in tbl2 which is NULL.

Comment: @drj A left join will give you single result set with all the records from both the tables. Where the join predicate is not true you will get NULL for the non matching rows: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-sql-outer-join.html

Comment: A good way to understand the OUTER JOIN/NULL concept is to remove the WHERE clause and then put a.*, b.* as your SELECT columns.  You'll notice that every row where there are matching fld columns, is the resultset of an INNER JOIN.  When you use LEFT OUTER JOIN you are asking SQL Server to return ALL rows of one table and information from another table regardless if it exists or not.  If it doesn't exist, something must still be returned which is why NULL is returned for an unmatched row.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way uses EXCEPT:

```
SELECT a.fld FROM tbl1 a
EXCEPT
SELECT b.fld FROM tbl2 b
```

Using the left join method:

```
Select distinct a.fld  
from  tbl1 a  
left join tbl2 b 
    on a.fld= b.fld
where b.fld IS NULL
```

You're currently looking for records where

`a.fld= b.fld` is true

AND `a.fld<> b.fld` is true

which, of course, is impossible.

Comment: It felt wrong yes :) Just didn't know what the right would be and why it would be right.   Using EXCEPT clause example, I believe you meant ..SELECT b.fld FROM tbl2 b.

Answer (score 0):

Change the where clause to the following:

```
where b.fld IS NULL
```

You can think of a left outer join as connecting records from two tables together (a working table), forming a new table with columns from both tables on each record.  All records from the A table are represented.  Columns from the A table are populated, but where there is not corrresponding B records, the columns  will be NULL.

Comment: Theoretically I understand this now. unfortunately there are no NULL records in tbl2 and thats what has been confusing me :)

Comment: The NULL will show up in the work table, not the source table.

Comment: `b.fld` will be `null` if the outer join does not find a corresponding row.